# mysql stored procedure call works manually, but not from java

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm calling a mysql stored procedure from Java like this:

```
public void deleteMyProduct(final String country, final String someId) throws EntityDoesNotExistException {
        getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback() {

            public Object doInHibernate(final Session session) {
                session.clear();    
                Connection con = session.connection();
                try {
                    CallableStatement cst = con.prepareCall("{call deleteProduct( ?, ? )}");
                    cst.setString(1 , country);
                    cst.setString(2 , someId);
                    cst.execute();
                    cst.close();    
                }
                catch(SQLException e){
                    logger.error("Error deleting product, someId:  "+ someId, e);
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
```

It's not successfully deleting the product; however when I run it manually, it does. Any idea what the problem could be?

p.s. the stored procedure is pretty large and contains identifiable info, so I'm not at liberty to post it. However, it's been in production for a while and only recently just stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you sure the code is getting executed?
2. Are variables `country` and `someId` actually correct?
3. What does the `SQLException` say?
4. Do get a successful connection - `Connection con = session.connection();`?
5. Are you passing the right types of variables(should you send `Int` instead of `String`)?

Comment: I would post this "answer" as a comment to the question, but it seems I need more reputation to do that..

Comment: How would I view SQLException? Yes variables are definitely correct. Also, I'm debugging the code through the execute of the stored procedure - but I can't walk into it.

Comment: What I meant with that was, if you get any exceptions thrown, but if you're debugging through it, I guess you would see if that would happen..

Comment: It turns out, the program was sending setting the variable the opposite of what they were in the stored procedure! When I ran the stored procedure manually I was setting them correctly, so I didn't notice that.